# How Can I scrape Value From Json Url?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to get Value (BestPrice) from json url and if its smaller than 250 - do something !
Url = https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Category=2&SortType=2&ResultsPerPage=1

I have Tried With Aphid Il post my code

```
while True:     




        resp = requests.get(f"https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Category=2&SortType=2&ResultsPerPage=1")

        data = json.loads(resp.text)

        P = Aphid.findall(data, ['BestPrice'])
        N = Aphid.findall(data, "Name")
        S = Aphid.findall(data, "Sales")


        print (f"  {N} Tracking {P} R$            Sales - {S}")
        if P < '250':
            print("VALID")
```

I want To Get BestPrice Clear Number And If Its Smaller Than 250  - Do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the 2nd half of your code to:

```
P = data[0]['BestPrice']
N = data[0]['Name']
S = data[0]['Sales']


print (f"  {N} Tracking {P} R$            Sales - {S}")
if P < '250':
    print("VALID")
```

should output

```
Shaggy Tracking 375 R$            Sales - 2,127,365
```